# Difficulty in loading boolean array using AVX2 instruction

Tags: c++, boolean, bit, avx2

Currently I have two boolean array X and Y which I want to do a bitwise or operation of both of them and store it back into X. I wish to do it using SIMD instruction but I find that the load instruction I used is not doing the expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(){
    bool mask[256]={0};
    mask[130] = 1;
    bool block_bloom[256]={0};
    bool a[256] = {0};
    __m256i reg1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(&mask[0]));
    __m256i reg2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(&block_bloom[0]));
    reg2 = _mm256_or_si256(reg1, reg2);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) &a[0],reg2);
    std::cout<< a[130] << std::endl;
    std::cout<<mask[130];
}
```

As I expected, this code should give the output 1 and 1, but instead the output is 0 and 1. I wish to know what have I done wrong and how to fix it. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `bool mask[256]` is 256 bytes not 256 bits. The minimum size of an array element is 1 byte. This means `mask[130]` is not loaded by `_mm256_loadu_si256`. You would need to pack your booleans into 256 bits before loading into the register:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t mask[32] = { 0 };
    mask[16] = 1 << 5;
    uint8_t block_bloom[32] = { 0 };
    uint8_t a[32] = { 0 };
    __m256i reg1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(&mask[0]));
    __m256i reg2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(&block_bloom[0]));
    reg2 = _mm256_or_si256(reg1, reg2);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) & a[0], reg2);
    std::cout << ((a[16] >> 5) & 0x1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ((mask[16] >> 5) & 0x1);
}
```

Comment: Ah thx a lot! May I ask further that how may I pack my booleans?

Comment: I am aware that I could use unsigned integers to store this bit array but are there any better ways? Thx again!

Comment: @WenKaiyue I've added an example

Comment: @WenKaiyue You can use `std::bitset`. However, I am not sure whether it is guaranteed to be trivially-copyable. In fact, I think it is not. Though, it seems to be with libstdc++ and libc++. Moreover, in these two implementations, it is even properly aligned for AVX2 instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/McbWz6Kc7.